# Linkurious dynamically change settlings

Tags: linkurious

I am currently using Linkurious and need to accomplish the following function:

Hide/show the labels when clicking on a button.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think Linkurious has provided a perfect solution.

```
s.settings({
            drawLabels: false
        });
s.refresh();
```

Cheers!